# Angular | Ionic 3 - How to create increment decrement product button?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I've readed many tutorial, but something is not yet clear.

I'm trying to create an increment decrement button, but without success.

I've multiple `h3` in a ion-list. This is my view:

```
<ion-step description="Step1 description" icon="checkmark">
            <div class="apartmentCapabilities" padding>
                <form class="app-form">
                    <ion-list *ngFor="let option of structur; let i = index">
                        <h3>{{ option.people }}</h3>
                        <h3>{{ option.bed}}</h3>
                        <h3>{{ option.bath}}</h3>
                        <h3>{{ option.night}}</h3>
                        <ion-item>
                            <ion-icon name="remove-circle" (click)="decrement()"></ion-icon>
                            {{currentNumber}}
                            <ion-icon name="add-circle" (click)="increment()"></ion-icon>
                        </ion-item>
                    </ion-list>
                </form>
            </div>
        </ion-step>
```

My goal is to have an increment decrement button foreach `h3`, somenthing like

"How many people: - 1 +".

this is my `.ts`:

```
private currentNumber = 0;

constructor() {}

private increment() {
    this.currentNumber++;
}

private decrement () {
    if(this.currentNumber>0){
        this.currentNumber--;}
}
```

Any help is appreciated. 
Have a nice day

Comment: What is the problem you are facing here? And also `increment()` and `decrement()` should be public.

Comment: I've tried to change to public the private increment and decrement function, but page is still blank, without content....any other idea?

Comment: Is the value of the variable updating as expected ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `private` from your functions. It should be public, that way template has access to your functions.

```
private currentNumber = 0;

constructor() {}

increment() {
    this.currentNumber++;
}

decrement () {
    if(this.currentNumber>0){
        this.currentNumber--;}
}
```

Comment: I've tried but it still not working. Have other idea?

Comment: what is change detection strategy? have you changed it from default one?